# destroy_all not working in transaction when we place a where clause before it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I experienced unexpected behavior. when I called `destroy_all` on a relation, it executed through an ActiveRecord transaction but when I placed a where clause before it, there is an unexpected behavior did that every record destroyed individually.

Example:

`Actor.find(1).movies.destroy_all` here `destroy_all` will run within a transaction, but
`Actor.find(1).movies.where(id: [1,2,3]).destroy_all` will commit every destroy individually.

There is an explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're dealing with different objects:

```
Actor.find(1).movies.class                    
# Movie::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy

Actor.find(1).movies.where(id: [1,2,3]).class 
# Movie::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation
```

And both classes define their own `delete_all` method in their own way:

```
# File activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb
def destroy_all
  @association.destroy_all.tap { reset_scope }
end

# File activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb
def destroy_all
  records.each(&:destroy).tap { reset }
end
```

So when you do `Actor.find(1).movies.destroy_all`, the action is handled by invoking `destroy_all` on `@association`.

But by doing `Actor.find(1).movies.where(id: [1,2,3]).destroy_all` there's an iteration for every object, invoking `destroy` on each of them.

`@association.delete_all` is defined to get an `ActiveRecord_Relation` and perform the destroy of the elements wrapping them in a single transaction:

```
def destroy_all
  destroy(load_target).tap do
    reset
    loaded!
  end
end
```

You could get the same result as in your first example, by experimenting with that method;

```
Actor.find(1).movies.instance_variable_get("@association").send(:destroy, Movie.all)
```

Comment: The thing is that `destroy_all` must instantiate every record in order to run its callbacks, that's why they run in their own transaction, if one of them isn't able to be deleted, others can without doing a rollback. The single transaction you see when using a CollectionProxy proxy seems to not work like that, and I'm not sure if it's okay. If you don't need to check every record callbacks, then you might use `delete_all` instead, or create your own transaction `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction { Actor.find(1).movies.where(id: [1,2,3]).destroy_all }`.

Comment: ```ActiveRecord::Base.transaction { Actor.find(1).movies.where(id: [1,2,3]).destroy_all }``` not working, I mean it working like calling ```destroy_all``` on relation

Comment: It seems to me that by wrapping the call to `destroy_all` in a transaction is causing the rollback, Bc as @SebastianPalma said, calling `destroy_all` as you're calling it, instantiates each record in it's own transaction to where it can be rolled back without affecting the others. But since you have that in another transaction, the entire tranasction gets rollback if one of the instantiated calls to destroy gets rolled back